# Testing: Unable to register MBean instance already exists

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, jmx

We have a few integration tests but recently we have faced a problem when a **@ManagedResource** is in the way:

```
Unable to register MBean [com.api.configuration.ApiConfiguration@63fde7ca] with key 'apiConfiguration'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: api:name=ApiConfiguration
```

And the offending bean looks like this:

```
@Component
@ManagedResource(objectName = "api:name=ApiConfiguration")
public class ApiConfiguration {

    @ManagedOperation   
    public void reloadConfiguration() {
        // do something
    }

}
```

We have tried adding a `@DirtiesContext` on every integration test without success.
The error only appears when running all tests from Maven or IntelliJ. If we run only one of the failing tests it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using java based configuration you only need to add this

```java
@EnableMBeanExport(registration=RegistrationPolicy.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

OR

```java
@EnableMBeanExport(registration=RegistrationPolicy.IGNORE_EXISTING)
```

So it will replace or use already existing bean (according to your configuration) and it will not give any kind of error

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear, there is an instance already and someone is trying to create another one. And it fails.

One way to solve this, when the problem is only showing on tests, is to ignore registration of duplicated mBeans:

```
<context:mbean-export registration="ignoreExisting"/>
```

Or if you prefer the annotation way:

```
@Autowired
MBeanExporter mBeanExporter;
```

And then set the policy to **ignore**:

```
mBeanExporter.setRegistrationPolicy(RegistrationPolicy.IGNORE_EXISTING);
```

By default the policy is set to **FAIL_ON_EXISTING**. You can also set it to **REPLACE_EXISTING**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation above your test, consider it to remove it. That helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this occurred during tests, a second configuration that enables jmx (and scheduling in my case) that is not enabled for integration tests solved the issue.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableMBeanExport
@Profile("!integrationtest") // Do not run for the integrationtest profile 
public class SchedulingConfiguration {

}
```

You also need to annotate your tests so they use the integrationtest profile:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("integrationtest")
class XServiceTest {
```